# Printing data from text file , the program always goes to the last record

Tags: c++, c++11

I have written a program that stores booking information in a text file in c++. So far I can search the booking number and check if that number exists in the text file and print "Record is found".

Now when I try to print the line in which the booking information is stored , the program always prints the last line in the text file.

for example it says that "Record 123 is found" but it prints the record "999" which is the last in the txt file.

Can you help me solve this problem by showing me some codes , about how I can print a specific line from a file.

My code is like this :

```
if ((i = search.find(x)) != search.end()) 
{ 
    cout << id << name << phone number << credit card number<<...endl;
}
```

this code allways prints the last line.

Comment: No, you should show some code so we can see what you did wrong. No-one can help you this way.

Comment: Please provide a little bit of *your* code. We can't see what functions you used, what structs/classes you've written yourself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's really hard to say what you're doing wrong when you posted zero code to show what it is you're doing. This is not a "please write my code for me" site. You need to post what you've tried so far, explain how (and where) it isn't working, and then someone can probably show you how to fix it. You *are* expected to demonstrate some effort yourself, though. Please edit your post to show what you've done so far. Thanks. :)

Comment: You have to provide code if you expect help with this.

Comment: My code is like this : if ((i = search.find(x)) != search.end()) { cout << id << name << phone number << credit card number<<...endl;} 

this code allways prints the last line.

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't make sense.  You are finding and getting an iterator to your item, but you are not using it to display your results.  Possibly you are printing locals you used to read through the file instead of using the iterator's values?

Comment: And it would really help if we knew what `search` was and the format of the type stored in `search`...

Comment: You've *still* posted no code that anyone can use to help you. If you want people to help you, you need to be willing to work hard enough to at least post an answerable question.

Comment: Everything is just string type , and I ask the user to enter the id for a booking to view it , so if the entered number is found I want to print the whole line. but my code allways prints the last line in the file.

Comment: Because this is just a university assignment, I'm affraid if I post the complete source code I'm gonna be in trouble because they are so serious about plagirism, they think I have copied and pasted the code from here.

Comment: Unfortunately, all we can do is make wild guesses unless you *show* us as much of the code as possible to reproduce your problem, the code you've shown above obviously isn't actual code.

Comment: Um, if we post the answer they'll think the same thing...

Comment: I just need to know how to print a specific line without knowing its line number or how to find it's line number. Just tell me how to it, I don't expect you to write me a program :d

Comment: With those requirements there's only one answer: _magic!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, we are left to guess blindly, and typically we don't have the patience for that (no offense, it's just that typically our guesses are wrong).

That said, I've got a hunch that what you are doing is using locals to read in your data and store them in some sort of structure (I'm guessing a `std::map`) and then when you search for the data you are finding it, but making the mistake of using the locals instead of the iterator.

You should be using your iterator (which you label `x` in your example) to output the data.  For example, if `search` is a `std::map`, then the data for the value is stored in the `second` part of the `std::pair` returned from `find()`:

```
auto x = search.find(x);

// this assumes your map's value is a struct with name, id, etc for fields.
if (x != search.end())
{
    std::cout << "Found: " << x->second.name << '\t' 
        << x->second.id << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much James, what you wrote was awesome , I never knew that I could print things this way. It is working and you are a c++ genius :D

Comment: I'd hardly call myself a C++ genius.  But you're welcome all the same.